# После перехода на новую гит-ветку грузит старые бинарники

Tags: visual-studio, angularjs, git, ionic, ionicframework

В проекте 2 ветки - login и registr.
Соответственно в ветке login - страница для входа, registr - для регистрации.
Сначала работал с login - изменял код, запускал отладку, коммитил.
После перехода на ветку registr - файлы в студии изменились (файл логина убрался, появился файл регистрации, как и должно быть), НО при запуске отладки я опять в браузере вижу страницу логина! (её последний вариант)

Что делал: clean и rebuild всего решения и проекта отдельно - не помогает.
На чём проект: Apache Cordova, Ionic Framework, AngularJS
Версия студии - 2015 Community 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: В браузере кэш чистили?

Comment: Нет, спасибо за совет, попробую. Если поможет - напишу сюда

Comment: Нет, не помогает. Зато нашел другой выход - забыл написать про используемые эмуляторы ведройда. Такие фокусы, которые я описал, происходят при использовании эмулятора Ripple-Nexus (Galaxy). Нашел решение:
1) переключаюсь на другой эмулятор - Google Android Emulator
2) запускаю отладку и жду построение билда
3) останавливаю отладку
4) переключаюсь обратно на рипл и запускаю отладку там
5) проффит (вижу нужные мне страницы)
рипл быстрее работает, поэтому не использую Google Android Emulator, и поэтому развожу танцы с бубном по этой теме